# Как добавить данные для записи через FileStream

Tags: c#

Я открываю файл через `new nFile = FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);`
Затем пишу в него данные `nFile.Write(text, 0, text.Length);` как можно добавить доп данные рядом после первых записанных ?

Comment: вызвать `Write` ещё раз?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, он почему-то перезаписывает

Comment: конечно перезаписывает, у вас `System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew`

Comment: Откройте документацию по классу `File`, там всё есть что вам надо. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, как вы именно добавляете данные в файл.
Если и в следующий раз в аргументы FileStream положите `FileMode.CreateNew`, то вам выдаст исключение, т.к файл уже создан.
Если нужно добавить в файл данные через уже созданный экземпляр FileStream , то ещё раз используйте `Write()`.
А если нужно добавить в файл данные из другой части кода:

1. Выберете `FileMode.Open` или `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.
2. Поставьте Position в конец `nFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);`
3. Используйте один из способов записи, например, `Write()`